# Rails: Why are white-spaces defined in templates shown?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, whitespace, actionview

Getting a little bit confused as to why these whitespaces are being taken literally.

If you take a look at the image below you'll see a bunch of rectangles. The top rectangle on the left should actualy align with the bar on the right but it doesn't because of a line break.

[image: screen shot of web-page with element inspector]

The rails code for this layout looks like this...

In the layout:

```
<div id = "left_bar"><%=yield(:left_bar)%></div>
<div id = "main_content"><%=yield%></div>
```

And in the actual template:

```
<div class = "set_area images current" id = "set_area_<%= @image_set.id %>">
  <%= render('images/images', :images => @image_set.images) %>
  <div class = "clear"></div>
</div>

<% content_for :left_bar do %>
  <% for set in @image_sets %>
    <%= render("set_tab", :set => set, :is_current_tab => set.eql?(@image_set))%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: Above code has slightly been simplified for brevity.

UPDATE: When I replaced the line to render the partial:

```
<%= render("set_tab", :set => set, :is_current_tab => set.eql?(@image_set))%>
```

with

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

The white-spaces didn't show up.

Comment: This seems more like a CSS issue. COuld you post the relevant css code , too?

Comment: I disabled the css entirely and I still had the same issue  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the issue to the "set_tab" partial. I started removing and re-adding in lines again.

I believe this went wrong because there were some mixed encodings. I mostly work on linux machine but I did some editing on a windows machine earlier in the day.

If anybody else find their view acting up like this throw out your indentation and redo it.